# How to access Product name and all details from sub Category using Django?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-templates

I want to get product name and all its details from sub category, I tried a lot to find how to do it but it didn't work

When clicking on the sub category the related products should appear ,If anyone knows the query please tell me

I have made four models
First Main category
Second category
Third SubCategory

Category contains the foregion key of the main category
Also
In sub category the foregion key of category is given

And in the product model, the foreign key of the above three models is given

I try this query Product.objects.all().select_related('main_category').select_related('category').select_related('sub_category')
Please tell me and its html part too